# Saving object in android in onSaveInstanceState()

Tags: android

This is a puzzle app. I have a class of Puzzle that contains the object itself and business logics. In onCreate, I created the object itself, I need to save the instance. Is it a good idea to save the same object I created in onCreate in onSaveInstanceState()? If so, what is the best way to do it? Otherwise, should I save the variables of the object Puzzle in onSaveInstanceState()?

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Read in the arrays
        String[] targetWords = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.target_words);
        String[] okWords = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.acceptable_words);

        // TODO: Now we always create a new puzzle when the Activity is created. You
        // will need to restore the existing activity if the Framework has destroyed
        // and recreated it.
        newPuzzle = new Puzzle(targetWords, okWords);
        for (int i = 0; i < newPuzzle.getGuessCount(); i++) {
            displayResult(i);
        }
    }

    // save the puzzle obj?
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your Puzzle Object Parcelable or Serializable, then save it in:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("puzzleObj", newPuzzle);
}
```

You can retrieve it in onCreate()

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        newPuzzle = (Puzzle) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("puzzleObj");
  }
```

Comment: Should I use the same object newPuzzle when retrieving the instance?

Also, should I have onSaveInstanceState for storing and onRestoreInstanceState for retrieving or do I just put everything in onCreate?

Comment: yes, you can use the same object if you like when retrieving the instance. It is better to retrieve the instance in onCreate(). onRestoreInstanceState() is called after onStart(), whereas onCreate() is called before onStart().